# Check if a sub or a function exist

Tags: vbscript, asp-classic

Is there any way to check if a sub or a function exist?

```
sub mySub()
 'some code
end sub
```

something like `if exist(mySub)`

Comment: If this is because you are linking multiple source files, you can add a `const x = true` to each then check for `x` later on

Answer (score 16, accepted):

#### Update:

So I knew there was a better method for doing this and it's using [`GetRef()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ekabbe10%28v=vs.84%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

```
Function Exist(procName)
    On Error Resume Next
    Dim proc: Set proc = GetRef(procName)
    Exist = (Not proc Is Nothing)
End Function

Function Hello()
    WScript.Echo "Hello Ran"
End Function

If Exist("test") Then  'Returns False (0)
    WScript.Echo "Test Exists"
Else
    WScript.Echo "Test Doesn't Exist"
End If

If Exist("Hello") Then  'Returns True (-1)
    WScript.Echo "Hello Exists"
Else
    WScript.Echo "Hello Doesn't Exist"
End If
```

Output

```
Test Doesn't Exist
Hello Exists
```

---

There is nothing built into VBScript to do this but you can build something using `On Error Resume Next` and `ExecuteGlobal()`.

```
Function Exist(procName)
    On Error Resume Next
    ExecuteGlobal "Call " & procName & "()"
    Exists = (Err.Number = 0)
End Function

Function Hello()
    WScript.Echo "Hello Ran"
End Function

If Exist("test") Then  'Returns False (0)
    WScript.Echo "Test Exists"
Else
    WScript.Echo "Test Doesn't Exist"
End If

If Exist("hello") Then  'Returns True (-1)
    WScript.Echo "Test Exists"
Else
    WScript.Echo "Test Doesn't Exist"
End If
```

Output

```
Test Doesn't Exist
Hello Ran
Test Doesn't Exist
```

*Drawback with this approach is it actually runs the procedure if it exists.*

Comment: Why **ExecuteGlobal**? I'm using your function using just **Execute** and works like a charm!

Comment: @Vixed `ExecuteGlobal` executes in the global scope where as `Execute` is scope dependent, it will work for simple commands but more complex ones I find `ExecuteGlobal` works better.

Comment: @Vixed There is a cleaner way of doing this and that is to use `GetRef()` I knew one existed *(used it before)* just couldn't remember the command. See updated answer.

Comment: I've built this function
`Function runIfExists(procName)
    On Error Resume Next
 Execute ("Call "&procName)
End Function`
But I get the an error **Error 'ASP 0115', Trappable error (C0000005)** Do you have any tips for me?!

Comment: @Vixed Nothing springs to mind, may be best asking another question and added the function you've built. In the mean-time maybe this will help, [Classic ASP : C0000005 Error on execution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4649487/classic-asp-c0000005-error-on-execution). I actually thought you had tested it and it worked, did you follow the code in the above answer, anything different? How you calling it for example?

Comment: Take a look: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35972186/asp-classic-execute-and-error-c0000005