# ASP Classic execute and error C0000005

Tags: iis, vbscript, asp-classic, iis-10

> **UPDATE:** If I disable AVG Free, **Execute** works fine
>
> This question is related to
>   [Classic ASP : C0000005 Error on execution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4649487/classic-asp-c0000005-error-on-execution)

My test.asp file contains just:

```
<%
execute("response.write 2+2")
%>
```

but yesterday after a windows update **[KB3140768](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3140768)**, all my  file that contains an `Execute()` command returns:

> Active Server Pages error 'ASP 0115'
>
> Unexpected error
>
> /test.asp
>
> A trappable error (C0000005) occurred in an external object. The script cannot continue running.

*IIS 10.0.1.10586.0 - WIN10 X64*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is caused by AVG Free update.

Comment: Ouch wouldn't use AVG if you paid me, way too many false positives. Prefer [Panda](http://www.pandasecurity.com/) at present.