# Classic ASP : C0000005 Error

Tags: asp-classic, 64-bit

Problem that the page work fine almost, But the few few time it will crash and show the error "C0000005".

When it occur the error, I refresh the page and try again or close the browser and re-open the page, it still work fine.

I have no idea to fix it.

Similar question that I found:

[Classic ASP : C0000005 Error on execution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4649487/classic-asp-c0000005-error-on-execution)

[ASP Classic execute and error C0000005](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35972186/asp-classic-execute-and-error-c0000005)

Answer (score -1):

sounds like a corrupt windows file, see here for more info:

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/carloc/2007/10/29/a-trappable-error-c0000005-occured-in-an-external-object-the-script-cannot-continue-running/

You may need to run a Repair & Fix on your machine and see if that resolves the issue