# A trappable error (C0000005) occurred in an external object

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, vbscript, asp-classic

I am calling a stored procedure named INSERT_BYTE with a string more than 4000 bytes . The code is a s follows :

```vb
Dim Conn
  Set Conn = Server.Createobject("ADODB.Connection")  
  Conn.Open "Driver={Oracle in XE};DBQ=xe;UID=biotpl;PWD=biotpl;"  

   strSQL = "INSERT_BYTE(1,'BQ0DAwA6EhlGd3d3d3d3d3d3d3d3d3d3d3d3d3d3CgcEADk4NjQyMS93d3d3d3d3DQYDADk3 NTMxMDAwd3d3d3d3DQcCADo3NDIwMC8ud3d3d3cMDQkAOzs2MjEvLi4td3d3d3cNCwYCATo0 MS8uLSwsKSZ3d3cVFA8OCzkyMC8tLCwrKnd3d3coIBcVEDgxLy8vLCsrKnd3d3c2EBgZGTsy Ly8vLSsqLHd3d3cQGB4eIDIzMDAvLi0rLHd3d3ccICQlJSwxMTIxLy4tMHd3d3ckJSkqKSwv MzU0MC8wMzV3d3cpKSwsLS8xNDU1Njc1NTV3dxwuLzAwMTI0ODk6AQQ6O3d3dx4dMjQzNDU3 OgEBAwQAAQR3dxYaNDY1Njk5OwABAQEBAgd3dxQXNjsHNgABAAABOjo7Ind3dw53AAMQEgwJ AQIEBy4tIh93dwkQEAAGEhcSBgMGDhoaIh53dwoMDBo4DRQUCAYOGREKOwd3dxMQCQ4MDRgW CQkYIwkGBHd3d3cLBwkOERAUEQ0QADk1AAp3dwYJCgU3KQsNDwwJBAA0NSJ3dwEIDQ4DAQsM BwUHCgc5OCB3d3d3d3d3d3d3d3d3d3d3d3d3N0E+HDhDPGhSKVNpK2dlQHR4NGktVW1cZipj GGo3WiQiNzAkMjwvNTpiRiskGydJclcdMGIjbmBZQ2dUSXQkckFuM2N5KCA3PUNISE5YYWVn bG59kJGSmJ+foKGkpKewsbK0trwKJCQoKCssMzY4Pj9DRUtMT1NUWF1gZmdnbHR0dICDhoaH iImLi40LDAEJFg0BDQEPDQsOFwoUCRUJExcJFgcPFxcJDBUXFxYAABcMDAkXAA8OBgYHEgIP DgUQDQMNDQwNDAAMCwwBDAEICw8VAwAuEhk+d3d3d3d3d3d3d3d3d3d3d3d3d3d3d3d3dwM7 NzY0MTEyd3d3d3d3d3d3BQQBOTYzMTAwL3d3d3d3d3cJBwUCOTUyMDAvLXd3d3d3d3cKCQYC OTYyMC8uLCt3d3d3dwwLCwg7NzQyMC4tKyt3d3d3dw4QEBgpMDc5Mi4tKyp3d3d3dxwSFSIk BAYJBDMtKyl3d3d3dy06MyonEQkPCDguKih3d3d3dygsLiksMgghLjMtKSh3d3d3FB8lJSUn KSsuLiwqKCZ3d3d3FhkfISMkIyUsLCopJyZ3d3d3dx4iJCQlJigqKikoJiZ3d3d3dyEkJicn KCkqKSkpKCd3d3d3dyUnKCkpKSorLC0sKih3d3d3d3ctLS0tLS4wMjEvLi53d3d3d3cxMTAw MDE0NTUzMjF3d3d3d3czMzMzMzQ1Nzc2NDN3d3d3d3c3NTU1NjY3ODg2Nnd3d3d3d3d3MDY4 ODg4OTk4OXd3d3d3d3d3dwgDAQI5OgEAAnd3d3d3d3d3AQMICAQ6AgoCd3d3d3d3d3d3Ajg1 BwI5BgoFd3d3d3d3d3d3BgZ3CAU7BAYCd3d3d3d3d3d3d3d3d3d3d3d3d3d3PlhGXkheTFdk aTksUyUsJzNSel5qREdZT25DaVxNWjJRQDpjO10yRGaAQm1lLmBBV05XSDouTHVvNzJpa1QA AAAAAAAAACsxNDQ5REVHTE1TV1peZGZnd3d4eH+JmJ6en6KnESgpLTAzNjc4OkJCQ0ZGR0hO UFFTVllddn+Aho2TqLa2AAAAAAAAAAAADQIMAwkUCQIBEAYEBhEFBA8QDw4PDQ0MCwwXDA0N CgEHCA4GCggSFxAPCwABEQUDAwQFBRAPDg0ODQwXCwAAAAAAAAAAAwA7EhlGd3d3d3d3d3d3 d3d3d3d3d3d3d3cEOzYzMC8wMTJ3d3d3d3d3dw8JOzUwLSssLjJ3d3d3d3d3dxMNOzEtKigq Ky4uLHd3d3d3dxscLiwnJSYpKSssLHd3d3d3dyEkKi0gISUoKSkqLHd3d3d3dyUoLwATHCAl JygoLC13d3d3dygrMAANFhwhJigoKyx3d3d3dykuMzsKEhYcIycpLC13d3d3dysvNDkFDBEW HyYqLi93d3d3dzUyNDkCBwwOEi0tLi13d3d3dwE2NTkBBQYHBTkyMTF3Bnd3dzQ0Njg7AwQE Azs2NTcNCQB3d3c1ODo7AgQDATs6OAAHBjR3d3c3OQACBAMDAQA7Ojo5NTN3dwR3OQADBAQC AQA7Ozk3NjJ3dxEQOwIDBAQDAjs2OTk3ODZ3d3cNCQcDAgQGBDo2OgE6ODh3dxALCAoAAAMG AwECAwMCAzt3d3d3dwkEAAMAOwMFBTo7Bwh3dx93CQgFCgwEAgUIBDYCCQ93dx0YdwcHBgwI BAkLER0LBgF3d3cNCAwJOzcGCQsICA4NATh3d3d3dwkGBgIIDjcAAQgOAzJ3d3d3d3d3d3d3 d3d3d3d3d3d3Txc6KEIkGUNKICA6J2sxZFlaOlRjOSluQk5nQT8uGSseMScNDVEaTCBLU1Bc FEYrJXFtZGJnbkhRXHtweC5VSYElZFguWR0hLC4uMDI9P0BHR1Bkb3qDiIyPlaCrrLKzuA4f JScoLDM0QERIS1BRVFVXWFxfZGlwc3V+f4uTlJqam52fn6OkpaWmqakDAAUQBQ0CBgUNAAgA DQwXAQwXCwwKFxQXCxYDBAYFEQIHCxADBQEHDRQPCw8BFwAMAQ0MAAwMFwALFw0MCxcMFRcL FwoLAwA0Ehk/d3d3d3d3d3d3d3d3d3d3d3d3d3d3d3cCADg3Nzk1MTIzd3d3d3d3dwQDAjs5 Nzg0MTEyd3d3d3d3dwcGBAA5NzUyMDAyMnd3d3d3CQgGBAE5NzQxMDEyMnd3d3d3BwYFAwA6 NzQyMjIyMHd3d3d3CwkGBAA6NzQyMjIxMDF3d3d3DQwJBQA6NjMxMTEwMC93d3d3EQ8NBwE4 MzExMTAwMDF3d3d3FhUTDQQ1MTAxMDAwMjF3d3d3GRkZFgw4MDAwLi4vLy93d3d3dx0fHxkw Ly4uLi4uLS13d3d3dyIiIiMkKy4uLi0tLCx3d3d3d3ckJSYlKy4uLy8tKyt3d3d3d3cmKCkq LC4uMDAuLCt3d3d3d3d3LCstLzAxMjExMi53d3d3d3c5NS0xMTEzNTQ0Nzt3d3d3d3d3Bzk3 NTE3ATg3ODh3d3d3d3cFCAMAOjg3NjY5And3d3d3d3cDdzsBATozNzo6BBJ3d3d3dzoDdwIE BRIqNgUBAXd3d3cCAToBBwIDBhQDNgQHAxJ3d3cBAAMECAkQHiQyAwgJd3d3dzoIBwQCHRYX ODc6CQU6d3d3d3d3d3d3d3d3d3d3d3d3d3d3Y2d6I1M7SDZIcE89f1heY1RPWjQrYS07Mzxp QEhAeoRpSWhTcl9rd0ZtSVdTQ2Bedms+WmhUWUsyYWpDLD1jAAAAAAAAAAwWLzJSUldiY2tv cnV4hI+apboRKy8/QEJLUF1eYnF7fo2Oj5CUlJWcnqGhoaKipqenqaqrrq+1uLi4ubu7uwAA AAAAAAAOAgIKAhcMBQQPAxEPDg4ACwkNDBcOCQsXCgMGAhIDDw4ODA4BAgENDA0LBwkXARAM FxcXDAYAAwsWFxcWBwwAAAAAAAAAAwA4EhlGd3d3d3d3d3d3d3d3d3d3d3d3d3d3dwgGBQMC AgA6ODh3d3d3d3d3BgYFBQQCATs5OXc4d3d3d3d3CAcGBgUDATs6Ojl3KXd3d3d3CgkICAcF AwQBOjg3d3d3d3d3CQgJCAgHBgMBOjk3Nnd3d3d3BwcJCAgHBQEAOzs6d3d3d3d3CwoKCQkH BQIBAAA6N3d3d3d3Eg0LCgoIBgUCAAA5NC53d3d3EA0MCgkIBwYDADo4NTF3d3d3DQwMCwkJ CQgGAwE6NTR3d3d3EQ4LDAsKCQkIBwkGODd3dzl3DwsJDA4IBwkIBwcGOzZ3dzl3DwwJCw8I BgcHBgQBOTZ3dxh3FQ8KDQsICAYDAgQEOzl3dxZ3ExAOEAwICQkFOwMEAgB3dwt3EhMODxIQ DAcDAAEAAgN3dwl3DxAQEBIQCQUBAA0uOgN3dwsPCgoNDQsHCBAUNwMLLRJ3dxMQCg0NDAkK FB8fLjcYISJ3dwN3CgwPEhANFBsbKjUqJSV3dwMGCgoMDw8MERQbLjUwIx53d3cOCQUJDhAO DAo2MzU1d3d3d3d3AgIIDhAYCwQ7NncCd3d3d3d3d3d3d3d3d3d3d3d3d3d3O1JnN3hhXWks SzGAWE8iWWBcVFhfWylONDVsYyFqe0IlbiVJW1g4UW8jh0tURDdWXm17WWN7aUVodFMiNEJt VXczU3NRZiM8bnBwcnV3gImQk5Sap6qxtLgVFh0xMTU+RlJaW1xdYGNmaGx2eHp6fHx8gICB goWGhoeIiYuPkJCSk5OVl5iZmpqdo6MLCwsKCxcWCwkVCQEHBxUTAg4XAA0MCxcKFgALCQsM CRUXFgsWFxYLFwkMFwoJCBYADAABDAsLFRcACBcVFgwUBhYGBAcBAAAA') " 
  Set objExec = Conn.Execute(strSQL)  
   If Err.Number = 0 Then  
Response.write("Process completed successfully...")  
  Else  
 Response.write("Error Save ["&strSQL&"] ("&Err.Description&")")  
 End IF
```

But I am getting the following error .

> Active Server Pages error 'ASP 0115'
>
> Unexpected error
>
> /data/2/famenroll2.asp
>
> A trappable error (C0000005) occurred in an external object. The
>   script cannot continue running.

How can I solve this error ? Please help me .

My SP is as follows :

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE 
   BIOTPL.INSERT_BYTE (pID IN NUMBER, 
   pData1 IN CLOB )
IS
   reallybigtextstring   CLOB := pData1;

BEGIN
   INSERT INTO TESTCLOB (ID, C, D)
   VALUES (pID, reallybigtextstring, 'done');
END;
```

Comment: can you post your sp ?

Comment: THe SP is given .

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Classic ASP : C0000005 Error on execution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4649487/classic-asp-c0000005-error-on-execution)

Comment: You know it's taken me less then [five minutes on Google](https://www.google.com/?gfe_rd=cr&ei=cL3fV4z_IaeN8QeiopGICg&gws_rd=cr&fg=1#safe=off&q=%2B%22A+trappable+error+(C0000005)+occurred+in+an+external+object%22%2B%22oracle%22) to find an abundance of information on this particular error. Here is a [promising blog article](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/carloc/2007/10/29/a-trappable-error-c0000005-occured-in-an-external-object-the-script-cannot-continue-running/) that suggests the Oracle driver is to blame, maybe there is a fix from Oracle?

Comment: The actual error pertains to an Access Violation which suggests the driver is trying to do something with memory it doesn't have access to. You best bet will likely be to ask Oracle about this and see if there is a fix or more recent driver.

Comment: I had the same error with classic ASP & MySQL.  Issue was somewhere in the ODBC or ADODB drivers, we never did work out exactly what the core problem was and just had to implement the functionality via a ASP.Net webpage to get around it.

Comment: make sure that your driver is working `{Oracle in XE}`. I just had (C0000005) errors as the driver stopped working with a change in character sets in the DB. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60100163/error-source-character-set-not-supported-by-client-when-field-set-to-uft8mb4-g