# Error "Source character set not supported by client" when field set to uft8mb4_general_ci

Tags: mysql, mariadb, odbc, character

Is this error a Windows MariaDB driver issue?

> [MySQL][ODBC 5.1 Driver][mysqld-5.5.5-10.2.12-MariaDB]Source character set not supported by client

I keep getting the error when trying to connect using this *asp* code:

```
Set rs = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
rs.ActiveConnection = Connection_STRING
rs.Source = "SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE text-str = 'some text'
rs.CursorType = 1
rs.CursorLocation = 2
rs.LockType = 1
rs.Open()
if (rsL.EOF) then
    ...
end if
rs.Close()
Set rs = Nothing
```

Comment: `uft8mb4_general_ci` is a _COLLATION_; `utf8mb4` is the corresponding _CHARACTER SET_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was only after changing **text-str** datatype form `VARCHAR` to `TEXT` that things started to work.

But some time later I found that I couldn't get any text from the table. I could save to it, but not get it back.

Was finally able to resolve it by changing the field's default collation from `uft8mb4_general_ci` to `uft8_general_ci`. And now VARCHAR also works.

---

The error I started after a Wordpress plugin update/removal. Somehow this changed some default settings to the database, and the way I was connecting to it was not working any more.

Installing an updated ODBC driver solved it.

Comment: solved mine by uninstalling the old odbc driver (5.1), restart, then installed the new version (8.0). big thanks! `[+1]`